# Launching a long running task from an AlertDialog (Android)

Tags: android, task, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog in and it's got a button, which, if selected, will initiate a file upload to a remote server like this:

```
builder.setMessage(text)                
.setCancelable(false)
.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
uploadFile();
}})
```

This works fine, the only problem is that uploadFile() can potentially take a long time (30 seconds to 2 minutes).  I would like to replace the AlertDialog with a progress dialog (even an indeterminate one), but I can't see how to launch one dialog from another?

Can anyone offer some advice for a how I could accomplish this.

Thanks,
Jarabek

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `AsyncTask` here, keep your `ProgressDialog` on the `PreExecute()` and call the method in the `doingInBackground()` and dismiss the ProgressDialog in the `PostExecute().`

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ActivityName.this, "Loading...", "Data is Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            uploadFile();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Then just call the `MyAsyncTask` using `new MyAsyncTask().execute();`

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this - using [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). There you can provide progress and do your long action