# Can't retrieve json content through an URL Android

Tags: android, json, url

I'm writing a small android app which will fetch json file content through an URL and then parse and format it.
But the content is not being fetched and my app showing "Unfortunately  has stopped".
Here is my [code](http://pastebin.com/ewPdB7Uy)

Here is the log error

> 09-12 18:37:15.565: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{my.tatasky/my.tatasky.TataskyActivity}:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>
> 09-12 18:37:15.565: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):   at
>   my.tatasky.TataskyActivity.readJson(TataskyActivity.java:154)

Comment: the error shows you are calling it nw operation on ui thread (from 3.0+ not permited in strict mode) switch to async task

Comment: refer this links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612406/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-need-to-use-async-task , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413625/android-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: check your image size and image name..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my apps i use gson. It is simple and fast:

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Example:

`GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.create();
gson.fromJson(json, MyObject[].class);`

Try run it on an new thread.