# App working fine in android 2.2 but unexpectedly closing in 4.2

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo, android-4.2-jelly-bean

The app is working absolutely fine in android 2.2. But in 4.2 the app is closing unexpectedly.
The app uses client server architecture to send messages to laptop that acts as the server.
the logcat shows:

```
02-07 04:49:45.683: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:45.683: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:45.690: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:46.160: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:46.203: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:47.803: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:47.810: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:48.000: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:48.050: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:48.182: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:48.190: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:48.262: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:48.440: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:48.440: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:48.470: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:48.480: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:48.480: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:48.500: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:48.550: D/gralloc_goldfish(829): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-07 04:49:49.030: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:49.060: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:49.210: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:49.210: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:50.433: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:50.433: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:50.473: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:50.473: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:50.860: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:50.860: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:50.993: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:50.993: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:51.040: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:51.040: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:51.490: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:51.490: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:51.530: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:51.530: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:52.003: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:52.003: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:52.070: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:52.070: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:52.503: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:52.503: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:52.563: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:52.563: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:53.011: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:53.011: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:53.071: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:53.071: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:53.540: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:53.540: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:53.600: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:53.600: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:54.020: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:54.020: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:54.100: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:54.100: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:54.550: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:54.570: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:54.750: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:54.750: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:49:55.070: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:50:20.590: D/dalvikvm(829): GC_CONCURRENT freed 193K, 11% free 2566K/2876K, paused 92ms+42ms, total 1402ms
02-07 04:50:20.590: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:50:20.610: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:50:20.653: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:50:20.660: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:50:20.750: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:50:20.750: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:50:21.284: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:50:21.290: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:50:21.355: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:50:21.360: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:50:21.560: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:50:21.560: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:50:21.610: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:50:21.768: W/Trace(829): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-07 04:50:22.083: D/AndroidRuntime(829): Shutting down VM
02-07 04:50:22.090: W/dalvikvm(829): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at com.example.sample2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:39)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at     android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-07 04:50:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 04:50:30.530: I/Process(829): Sending signal. PID: 829 SIG: 9
```

My client code is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private Socket client;
 private PrintWriter printwriter;
 private EditText textField;
 private Button button;
 private String messsage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            messsage = textField.getText().toString(); 
            textField.setText("");    
            try {

                client = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 4444);  
                printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
                printwriter.write(messsage);  
                printwriter.flush();
                printwriter.close();
                client.close();  
               } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
               }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Please help me resolve it.

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, stack trace says it all. [More information](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html).

Comment: It did work fine on older versions of Android, because that older version of the framework code would never check for this condition.

Comment: Clearly. I know exceptions are not always understandable, but this one says it all. Put you networkd communications with your server in a separate thread (with AsyncTask for example..)

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException . Need to use async task?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612406/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-need-to-use-async-task)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0

Answer (score 1):

You're performing a network operation in your main UI thread. If your target SDK is 11 (Honeycomb) or higher this will throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` , because this behaviour can block the UI and lead to an unresponsive app.

You could use an `AsyncTask` to get around this, by loading the data in its `doInBackground(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take your network activity off of the main thread.

Take a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)'s

Comment: you're like the 1 millionth person to ask this. Try to google for AsyncTask and see how to use it. Please read the link someone posted by A-C.

Comment: @user2048724 Android no longer supports network operations on the main (GUI) thread.  This means all network operations need to be moved to another thread.  AsyncTask is a nice tool the dev team at Android have given us to do so.  Do some research on what Threads are and on MultiThreading.